# Creating a PNG from uncompressed raw PNG data

Tags: javascript, android, c

I am using this [Android Screenshot Library](https://github.com/iyouq/android-screenshot-library/blob/master/native/fbshot.c) to capture screenshots. I want to show this screenshot in web browser.

I have written a small socket app on PC which connects to Android phone and encode the captured screenshot to base64.

```
String base64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);
```

This base64 is being sent to web page over websocket. Below is my html/JS code which should draw the image on canvas. I have stored the base64 image data in a text file for test purpose.

```
<div style="background: aqua; width: 500px; height: 660px;">

    <canvas style="width: 480px; height: 640px;" id="sim">
    </canvas>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var ctx;
    var width = 480;
    var height = 640;

    (function start() {
        ctx = document.getElementById("sim").getContext("2d");
        loadFromFile();
    })();

    function loadImage(data) {

        var image = new Image();
        image.onload = function() {
            //this part never executes
            ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
            console.log("images loaded!");
        }

        image.src = "data:image/png;base64," + data;
    }

    function loadFromFile() {
        //please get data from **https://app.box.com/s/e19ww51fd37h4sy8getjnag31ud6tpp9**
        var file = "imagefile.txt";

        var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
        rawFile.open("GET", file, true);

        rawFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (rawFile.readyState === 4) {
                if (rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0) {
                    var data = rawFile.responseText;
                    console.log("data loaded: " + data.length);

                    loadImage(data);
                }
            }
        }
        rawFile.send(null);
    }
</script>
```

For convenience, here is the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amebgfvk/) of same code.

Please point to right algorithm as how to generate the PNG from the raw uncompressed data. code sample would be great ;)

Thanks

Comment: are you sure your `data` parameter is the base64 string?

Comment: what data do you have in loadImage(data)?Probably image.onerror will execute

Comment: 'data' is base64 image data and I am able to load it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static String encodeTobase64(Bitmap image)
{
Bitmap immagex=image;
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
immagex.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
String imageEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(b,Base64.DEFAULT);

Log.e("LOOK", imageEncoded);
return imageEncoded;
}

public static Bitmap decodeBase64(String input) 

{
byte[] decodedByte = Base64.decode(input, 0);
return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedByte, 0, decodedByte.length); }
```

Comment: Tricky! It works beautifully though I wanted to understand how could it be done in JavaScript. But I guess it makes not sense to do it in browser when we have API on device itself. Accepting it as answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Dear Response.

Comment: Um, except that JPEG is not what you asked for nor is it the appropriate format for screen captures. It will produce awful quantization noise. PNG is the only appropriate format for drawings, logos, and similar non-photographic images.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker - yes, I wanted in PNG format and thats really easy to do, just change the flag `Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG` to `Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG` :)

Answer (score 0):

### Note that

1) set dimension of canvas not by style or css, only this way

```
<canvas width="480" height="640">
```

or

```
canvas //canvas variable
canvas.width = 480;
canvas.height = 640;
```

2) To draw image with dimension of canvas, do this way

`ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width,image.height);`

or

`canvas.width=image.width;
canvas.height=image.height; 
ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);`